# When overriding the method of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter class eclipse shows error in spring-security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to make different user name with different role in my Spring-MVC for login and logout page.

I have studied from below link and I am using spring 4.2.5:

http://www.raistudies.com/spring-security-tutorial/role-based-spring-jsp-taglibs/

but one of my class is showing an error:

```
public class AjaxAuthenticationProcessingFilter extends
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, authResult);
    }
}
```

Eclipse showing compile time error on method,

> The method successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, Authentication) of type AjaxAuthenticationProcessingFilter must override or implement a supertype method

and other error is when I call `successfulAuthentication` method of
super class `super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, authResult);`.

You can see the error given below:

> The method successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain, Authentication) in the type AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter is not applicable for the 
>        arguments (HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, Authentication)

If anyone knows any link for spring security to implement different users with different role then please let me know with the help of spring-xml configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code..check your imports.

**And Mainly**

```
successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,Authentication authResult)
```

is deprecated.

**Use**

```
successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,FilterChain a, Authentication authResult)
```

Finally,

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

public class AjaxAuthenticationProcessingFilter extends
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,FilterChain filter, Authentication authResult)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response,filter, authResult);

    }

}
```

Comment: i am still getting some errors in my spring security app if u know any helpful  link for spring security basics  then please let me know

Comment: Actually for spring security you should go through spring docs..there is no particular site which describes about security or oauth.